# How to find most frequent used class on a web page with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, dom

Wondering if there's a way to show the list of classes used on a page with # of times it occurs on the page. Like so:

```
sublevel | 12
tag | 10
main | 1
```

Comment: I think your only option is to traverse the DOM, maintain a map of present classnames during, sort and select. You should include your attempt(s) so far, as this question currently shows very little effort or independent research.

Comment: Well, you could kinda brutforce it for sure ex.create an 2d array of strings and counts loop through all document elements, get it's class, if your array contains it, then increase the count, if it doesn't then add and set the value to 0. But i don't think that's the best solution haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as most of the others: get all elements and loop over them, counting the number of times each *className* appears. Only difference is it tries to be compatible with browsers back to say ES5. Needs [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill), [*forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) and [*Object.create*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill) polyfills for IE 8.

```js
function countClasses(root) {
  root = root || document;
  return [].reduce.call(root.getElementsByTagName('*'), function (classes, el) {
    (el.className.match(/\S+/g) || []).forEach(function(cls) {
      classes[cls]? ++classes[cls] : classes[cls] = 1; 
    });
    return classes
  }, Object.create(null)); 
}

console.log(countClasses());
```

```html
<div class="foo bar">
 <span class="foo"></span><span class="bar fum"></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**CSS Attribute Selector**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute.asp) to select all the elements that have the attribute `class`. Then loop through each element of the set, accessing its `className` property and counting the occurences of each class:

```js
var classes = {}; // the classes counter

document.querySelectorAll("[class]").forEach(function(el) {   // select all the element that have a class attribute
  el.className.trim().split(/\s+/).forEach(function(clazz) {  // get the className of this element, trim it, and split it into individual classes
    // for each class, increment or initialize the counter
    if(classes[clazz]) classes[clazz]++;
    else classes[clazz] = 1;
  });
});

console.log(classes);
```

```html
<div class="A B">
  <span class="B"></span>
</div>
<p class="A B C"></p>
```

Comment: What is this `$`?

Comment: @FelixKling not a big difference anyway!

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. Relevant standards such as [*W3C*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) or documentation such as [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) are preferred. Selectors are not exclusively for CSS, they're an independent technology for finding elements in a DOM, so just "[*attribute selector*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in API for something like this. You need to inspect the class names of every element. To get every element you either have to walk the DOM or get a list of all elements and iterate over them. Here is a simple solution that does the latter:

```
const classes = new Map();

for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  for (let cls of elem.classList) {
    classes.set(cls, (classes.get(cls) || 0) + 1);
  }
}

const rankedClasses = Array.from(classes).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]);
```

Can't say whether walking the DOM is more efficient or not.